# Delay before TX in RS485

Tags: rs485

I want to understand why we need to add delay before and after we send TX data for using RS485.
And how do I calculate the delay time.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a peak after transmitting when the driver leaves the line, I just have taken it:[image]
I recommend 50us for a 5m cable